# Is there analytic solution for my Eq

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Is there analytic solution to this Eq :

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{B(\frac{1}{y^2}-4y+3y^2)+Dy^2}$$

where $B,D$ are constants

Comment: Yes this is a separable ODE, so you have

$$
\int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{B(\frac{1}{y^2}-4y+3y^2)+Dy^2}}=\int dx=x+C.
$$
The integral on the left can be expressed in terms of elliptic integrals, see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2Fsqrt%281%2Fy%5E2-4y%2B3y%5E2%2By%5E2%29

Comment: this not solution !! this is Hell itself :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is analytic if you want to express the integral in terms of elliptic integrals.  This is a separable ODE, we integrate both sides to obtain

$$
\int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{B(\frac{1}{y^2}-4y+3y^2)+Dy^2}}=\int dx=x+C.
$$

The integral on the left can be expressed in terms of elliptic integrals, see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2Fsqrt%28a*%281%2Fy%5E2-4y%2B3y%5E2%29%2Bb*y%5E2%29